# Why is my HTML id attribute invalid, when I have 4x the same id plus a counter?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, w3c-validation, radiobuttonlist

I have a form with a group of 4 radio buttons and for some reason unknown to me, my fourth radio does not work...

JSBIN here: [radio madness](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/1265/edit)

I ran the code through the W3C validator and it complains that on the 4th radio the `label` element must refer to a `form input`.

Looking at my 3rd and 4th radio labels and input...

```
    <label for="dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-6205-5265c866f79f_content_type_2">Structured Text</label>
    <input type="radio" id="dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-6205-5265c866f79f_content_type_2" name="dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-6205-5265c866f79f_content_type" value="text/structured">
```

This works, while this:

```
    <label for="dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-6205-5265c866fa79f_content_type_3" data-i18n="">reStructuredText</label>
    <input type="radio" id="dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-620a5-5265c866f79f_content_type_3"  name="dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-6205-5265c866f79f_content_type" value="text/x-rst">
```

fails. It must be something related to the `id-attribute` because if I just use `a, b, c` as `id`, the code passes. I have looked up `id` limits and it cannot be a length issue, plus I'm starting with a character, so for me it's ok.

**Question:**
Why is the `id` attribute of the 4th radio button invalid, when the other three are working ok?

Thanks for enlightenment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same, so your label *doesn't* refer to a form element...

```
                                 **
for: dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-6205-5265c866fa79f_content_type_3
id:  dyno_fe7ee1e9-6005-69e7-620a5-5265c866f79f_content_type_3
                                 **
```

Comment: mh... that is a valid point.